# Get information with Sweetalert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

My question is if is there a way to use sweet alert to get a text like in window.prompt

FOR EXAMPLE: var name =window.prompt("Write your name","");

¿Can i do that with sweetalert ?*

Comment: Did you try it? Does sweetalert not have any documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-dom-nodes-as-content), it appears the following promise will return the content of the input.

```
swal({
  text: 'Search for a movie. e.g. "La La Land".',
  content: "input",
  button: {
    text: "Search!",
    closeModal: false,
  },
})
.then(name => {
  console.log(name);
})
```

Comment: Yes, i was wanting something like that, i only change the console.log(name);  for swal("Hi "+name); THANKS.